# Calculate unrated items with cosine similarity

Tags: python, pandas, recommendation-engine

I want to calculate unrated items with cosine similarity with this method.

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

dff = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, (5, 3)))
temp = dff.copy()
dff
    0   1   2
0   8   0   4
1   6   9   4
2   5   0   5
3   5   9   4
4   9   4   8

cossim = cosine_similarity(dff) # calculate scores.
cossim

array([[1.  , 0.62, 0.95, 0.57, 0.92],
       [0.62, 1.  , 0.61, 1.  , 0.83],
       [0.95, 0.61, 1.  , 0.58, 0.95],
       [0.57, 1.  , 0.58, 1.  , 0.81],
       [0.92, 0.83, 0.95, 0.81, 1.  ]])
```

I want to calculate 0 values with cosine similarity score.

```
for x in range(0,dff.shape[1]):
    indexes = dff.index[dff.loc[:,x]==0].tolist()
    for y in indexes:
        dff.loc[y,x] = (cossim[y]*temp.loc[:,x].to_numpy()).sum()
dff

    0   1   2
0   8   21.307945   4
1   6   9.000000    4
2   5   34.528532   5
3   5   9.000000    4
4   9   4.000000    8
```

I calculate it with two for loop?
Is there any pythonic way to calculate it?

There is test data (real values)

```
import numpy as np; import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
data = [['aa',1, 10], ['aa',2,6], ['aa',3, 5],['aa',4],
        ['bb',1], ['bb',2,5], ['bb',3,8],['bb',4,6],
        ['cc',7], ['cc',2], ['cc',3,4],['cc',4,9]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['full_name','user_id', 'rating'])  
repo_matrix = df.pivot_table(index='full_name', columns='user_id', values='rating')
repo_matrix.replace(np.nan, 0, inplace=True)
repo_matrix
cossim = cosine_similarity(repo_matrix)
display(cossim)
temp = repo_matrix.copy()
repo_matrix = temp.mask(temp==0, cossim@temp)
repo_matrix
```

All zeros convert to NaN. ??

Comment: Why `[3,1]` is replaced by `cossim[1]*dff.loc[:,1]...`? shouldn't it be `cossim[3]*dff.loc[:,1]...`

Comment: 1. columns values are in cossim(1)

Comment: so the zero at `[4,1]` will get the same value?

Comment: nope, it calculate score with each similarity score of cell.

Comment: I solve it with 2 for loop but  I am looking for a pythonic way

Comment: You really need to review your logic: *nope, it calculate score with each similarity score of cell*  doesn't go along with `cossim[x]*dff.loc[:,x].to_numpy()`. The former says that each cell is different, the latter says they are the same.

Comment: ok I got it. `dff.loc[y,x] = (cossim[y]*temp.loc[:,x].to_numpy()).sum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operation is just matrix multiplication. So you can do:

```
 # pass the numpy array instead of dataframe
 # also, you don't need to copy to temp 
 dff = dff.mask(dff==0, cossim @ dff.values)
```

Output:

```
   0         1  2
0  8  14.35119  4
1  6   9.00000  4
2  5  14.49324  5
3  5   9.00000  4
4  9   4.00000  8
```

Comment: It works on sample dataframe but on real data, all 0 values convert to NaN.

Comment: Does your dataFrame have column names? Also, do you have a row/column where it’s all 0/nan?

Comment: Yes, it has a column name. I add test data to my question.

Comment: That's the problem. You can pass the numpy array instead of the dataframe. See updated.

Comment: Can I ask last thing :) I want to get topK values (among we changed) from each column. I copy dataframe to get these values (zero values.) Then I planned to get their indices from copied dataframe. For example, `1 => 14.49 and 14.35 `

Comment: I'm not sure there's a short solution, but you can try: `dff.apply(pd.Series.nlargest, n=2)`